# Compilation Error on Linq query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Following on from my previous question, I am getting another compilation error on my Linq query:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
```

Source Error:

```
Line 42:  XElement xml = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("/members/listmembersxmlfeed?gid" + gid));
Line 43: 
Line 44:  var query = from p in xml.Descendants("member")
Line 45:    select new
Line 46:    {
```

This is the entire procedure:

```
protected void exportList(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String gid;
    gid = Request.QueryString["gid"].ToString();
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("/members/listmembersxmlfeed?gid" + gid));

        var query = from p in xml.Descendants("member")
                select new
                {
                    Name = p.Element("name").Value,
                    Email = p.Element("email").Value
                };

        foreach (var member in query)
        {
                Response.Write("Employee: " + member.Name + " " + member.Email + "<br />");
        }
}
```

I've checked the code against the example on the Microsoft website and it looks good. I've also checked to see if 3.5 is referenced correctly for the website, which I believe it is.

Thanks.

Comment: gid is the Group ID passed as a query string.

Of note is the fact that this website works on my local testing server, but not on my public server, which leads me to believe that 3.5 may not be reference properly, however I have checked the web.config and the references are there.

Comment: Do you have "using System.Linq;" in your using-directives for the file in question? And what line number is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: Line 44 is the indicated error line.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine.  Are you sure it isn't somewhere else that a ; is missing?

Comment: And what about "using System.Linq;"?

Comment: I wonder whether it is a 3.5 or Linq reference, but without posting the entire web.config it's going to be hard to decide whether that is the problem. The Linq reference is at the top of the page as we're using Umbraco master pages. 

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Linq" %>

Comment: Are you saying the using statement is in the master page or in the actual page? And is the code in question in the master page or the actual page?

Comment: The using statement is on a master page, the code is within a code block, on the master page, is there a larger comment block available on Stack Overflow so I could post the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the web.config into Visual Studio and changed the build to 3.5 in the properties, this seems to have solved the problem. Clearly there was a reference missing, but I am at a loss as to which one it was.

Thanks for all your help.